# Can I build a 3D image of a warrior type character if I only have one image of that character from one frontal view

Tags: 3d-models

Ok I’m so new at Blender. Half the time it’s knowing what question you have to ask to get the answer you need...

I want to make a 3D printable warrior type action figure but I only have one very detailed frontal view. Can I input that image into somewhere and it gives me a 3D model to start from? Like will it generate a 360 view? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Although this question is linked to 3D printing, it might attract better answers at Blender SE.

Comment: That said, please don't cross-post the same question across SE sites. If you do decide to post on SE.Blender, then close/delete this question first.

Comment: This is a duplicate of (take your pick): This is for one photo: [Can I use a 2D photo to get a 3D printing model? \[closed\]](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/7397/4762), these two are for multiple photos: [How to optimally make a 3D model of an object using photos?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/1477/4762), or [How can I get a 3D model from a bunch of 2D photos?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/7805/4762)

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. A 2D image has insufficient information to determine a 3D form.

If you want to do this yourself, what you could do is start with the 2D outline in a program like Blender (as 0scar mentioned in a comment), extrude it to make a thin "cardboard cutout", then begin shaping it into three dimensions from there. Imagine it like cutting a slab of Play-doh with a cookie cutter matching your 2D outline, then using the picture and your imagination as a guide to form it into 3D. I'm not sure whether something like that makes any more sense than just starting from scratch modeling it.

Alternatively, nowadays there *might* be some "AI" models to produce a reasonable guess at what 3D structure you want, with the knowledge that it's supposed to be a person, for a 2D image you provide. I'm not sure if there's anything yet of usable quality, but it's something you could look for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It is sufficient for making a 3D model, but not in the way you want. Basically, you cannot turn a 2D image into a 3D model automatically, so you will have to do it manually. The image you have can be used as a reference image, and you will have to use some artistic freedom when creating the backside. It is basically the digital version of creating a clay sculpture based on an image. Perfectly possible, but it does require quite a bit of skill and patience.

If you want to learn how to do it, search for beginner tutorials on YouTube about ‘sculpting’ in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a 2D photo then as others have already said its not really possible.  However if you have the action figure itself you could try a technique called Photogrammetry where you use your phone to take multiple images of the object and then use software to build up a model. Search youtube for guides on Photogrammetry or 3D scanning with your phone. I've never done it but certainly something I'd like to try!